# Google App Engine ndb order by length of StringProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sql-order-by, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to order a query by the length of a StringProperty? I tried this:

```
User.query(User.facebook_id = fb_id).order(-len(str(User.name))).fetch(10)
```

but it displays me the error: TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a [Computed Property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed):

```
name_len = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: len(self.name))
```

and then make your query with it:

```
User.query(User.facebook_id = fb_id).order(-User.name_len).fetch(10)
```

If that doesn't work, then you will need to add an `IntegerProperty` and set it to the length of the string (`name_len = ndb.IntegerProperty()`)

Comment: I had already did the second one, but it's pretty annoying that I need another Property for this.